NSWindow on top of other full screen applications
I'm programmatically creating an NSWindow and have set its level and other properties, but it doesn't appear on top of other apps. Using NSPanel works, but I prefer not to use it since it doesn't support full-screen mode.
func openDummyWindow() {
    let controller = NSWindowController()
    let window = NSWindow(
        contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 600),
        styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
        backing: .buffered,
        defer: false
    )

    // tried with .floating, .mainMenu but none worked
    window.level = .screenSaver 
    window.collectionBehavior = [.canJoinAllSpaces, .fullScreenAuxiliary]
    let contentView = ZStack {
        Color.clear
        Text("Hello")
            .font(.system(size: 72))
    }
    window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
    window.center()
    controller.window = window
    controller.showWindow(nil)
}

I've spent 6-7 hours trying, but no luck so far. It would be a huge help if someone could assist with this.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/openwindow

I have put your code in a fresh project and call openDummyWindow from applicationDidFinishLaunching. The window that is created stays on top of other app's windows. What else do you expect?

Really? It's not working for me

"It's not working for me" does not say that much. Is the window created at all?

Window is created but not on top of the full-screen windows, opened directly on Desktop only
